# NAudio - Convert any wav file format to raw PCM

Tags: c#, .net, naudio

It is easy to use NAudio to convert MP3 and arbitrary wav files to a specific wav file format. No problem with this. But I cannot figure out how to convert MP3 or wav to raw PCM s16LE files (22050khz, 16bit, mono) as the target format.

How can I do this with NAudio?

Here is my code for converting from wav files. It is essentially the same code for other input formats:

```
using (var reader = new WaveFileReader("input.wav"))
{
    var outFormat = new WaveFormat(22050, 16, 1); 
    using (var conversionStream = new WaveFormatConversionStream(outFormat , reader))
    {
       WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("output.wav", conversionStream);
    } 
}
```

This code produces a wav file format with RIFF headers, but as mentioned, I need a raw PCM s16LE file.

Comment: What source code are you using for the conversion so far? Would you please edit your answer and share it? Thanks

Comment: Added code sampIe I use to convert to a specific wav format.

Comment: There is no standard that dictates what a raw PCM file should look like.  Consider creating your own and use BinaryWriter's to write the 16-bit values.   But focusing on how that file is going to be read again is not something to skip.

Comment: @HansPassant The reader application expects for performance reasons exactly this format: s16LE (22050, 16, 1). So for the reader application there is no need to have a container like WAV since it only can read raw PCM. It's an external application.

Comment: Well, make it so, nobody here can verify that this app can correctly interpret the file content.  The WAV container is *very* thin, and today's computers far more powerful than 27 years ago, if it can read wav then don't make the mistake of not using it.